# What format should I use for citing a regulation

Tags: united-states, regulations

I want to cite section II.C.2.b of [this proposed rule](https://www.federalregister.gov/articles/2016/05/09/2016-10032/medicare-program-merit-based-incentive-payment-system-mips-and-alternative-payment-model-apm) in my comments to the federal agency (Medicare). Is "II.C.2.b" the correct format? Or II(C)(2)(b)? Something else?

I can't find online anywhere how I am supposed to format different bullet levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Federal Register citations, people typically cite the codified version.  The generally accepted standard for U.S. legal citations is the BlueBook, and in this case Rule 14...but [this excerpt](http://libraryguides.nesl.edu/content.php?pid=358326&sid=2934955) might get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are citing to the proposed rule, one normally cites to the page number in the Federal Register.

You would download the PDF from the web site you linked to in order to find the page numbers.